# Mass, field renormalization in QED

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, self-energy

I am trying to understand the formula for mass and field renormalization in QED from the book Gauge theory by Bohm, Denner, pp $202$. They use renormalized perturbation to rewrite the Lorenz gauge fixed Lagrangian with $$A_\mu^0=Z_A^{1/2}A_\mu,\; \psi_0=Z_\psi^{1/2}\psi, \;e_0=Z_ee,\;, m_0=Z_mm,\;\xi_0=Z_\xi\xi,$$ where the symbols are well known within QED. After this, they directly write:

The constants $Z_m$ and $Z_\psi$ for the renormalization of the electron mass and field are fixed by
$$
\lim _{p^2 \rightarrow m^2}\left[\frac{(\not p+m) \Gamma_{\mathrm{R}}^{\psi \bar{\psi}}(p,-p) u(p)}{p^2-m^2}=u(p)\right] .
$$

I do not understand this formula. I have done the mass and field renormalization by summing over the $1PI$ diagrams and getting:

$$
iG=\frac{iZ}{\not{p}-m+i\Sigma(\not{p})}
$$
and then on-shell renormalization: $\Sigma|_{\not{p}=m_p}=0$ and $\partial_{\not{p}}\Sigma|_{\not{p}=m_p}=0$. So, what is the relation between the two approaches?

Comment: Is this for a course?

Comment: no, personal interest

Comment: Are you familiar with the relationship between terms in the 1PI effective action and n-point correlation functions? (Also, in case you missed it, the "single" renormalization condition at $p^2\rightarrow m^2$ is really "two" in disguise, because of the singularity in $\not p - m$ in the denominator.) Could you provide slightly more context?